# Azure Servicebus queue is locking messages or queues in my Java 8 program

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-servicebus-queues

I have 2 Azure servicebus queues: queue1 and queue2.  I want to copy or move messages between these two queues with Java. I use these dependencys in my Maven file from Azure:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>7.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.41.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

I use this code for creating my Azure receiverClient and senderClient:

```
this.receiverClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                        .connectionString(props.getProperty("connection-string"))
                        .receiver()
                        .queueName(props.getProperty("queue1"))
                        .receiveMode(ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK)
                        .buildClient();
            
            this.senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                    .connectionString(props.getProperty("connection-string"))
                    .sender()
                    .queueName(props.getProperty("queue2"))
                    .buildClient();
```

I use a function to copy or move the messages from queue1 to queue2 like this:

```
public void readMessagesFromQueue() {
        //"number of messages" is 1500 and the "duration-read-queue"  is 100
        IterableStream<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> messages = receiverClient.receiveMessages(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("number of messages")), 
                Duration.ofSeconds(Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("duration-read-queue"))));

        for (ServiceBusReceivedMessage serviceBusReceivedMessage : messages) {

            String messageBody = serviceBusReceivedMessage.getBody().toString();
            Map<String, Object> mapQueueProperties = serviceBusReceivedMessage.getApplicationProperties();
            
            ServiceBusMessage serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(messageBody);
            serviceBusMessage.getApplicationProperties().putAll(mapQueueProperties);

            //write the message to the local file system as a file and also the propertys
            writeMessageToFile(serviceBusMessage.getBody().toString(), fileTeller);
            writePropertiesToFile(serviceBusMessage.getApplicationProperties(), fileTeller);

            senderClient.sendMessage(serviceBusMessage);
            
            //if it is a move from queue to queue the original message must be deleted
            //if it is a copy from queue to queue the original message must NOT be deleted
            if (props.getProperty("copy").trim().startsWith("move")) {
                receiverClient.complete(serviceBusReceivedMessage);
            } else if (props.getProperty("copy").trim().startsWith("copy")) {
                receiverClient.abandon(serviceBusReceivedMessage);
            }

        }
        
        receiverClient.close();
        senderClient.close();
    }
```

When I run the program sometimes I get errors. For example when I move 1300 messages from queue1 to queue2 then it runs fine.
But when I copy the messages within a minute or so from queue2 back to queue 1 then it gives errors like this:

Delivery not on receive link.
2023-08-10 07:51:34 ERROR MqWorkService:230 - com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: Delivery not on receive link.
2023-08-10 07:51:34 ERROR MqWorkService:230 -   at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.lambda$updateDisposition$52(ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.java:1478)

The error occurs on this line of code:

```
receiverClient.complete(serviceBusReceivedMessage);
```

When I wait 5 minutes or so then sometimes the copy can happen sometimes I need to wait for 10 minutes or 15 minutes.

So it is a very unreliable queueing system, at this moment.

We use a standard Azure ServiceBus licence. The queues are created with a a Message Lock Duration of 10 seconds in the Azure service bus portal.

Also when the Java program is shutting down after succesfully processing the messages, it takes exactly a minute before the application exits. Can I use something like this:

```
System.exit(0)
```

for faster exiting ?

What I am doing wrong, why I am getting these errors ?

There must be some locks on the queues I think, but why ?

In the error there is also refered to a ServiceBusReceiver**Async**Client. But In my code I only use a ServiceBusReceiverClient and not the Async.

Comment: What's the maximum lock duration on each of the queues?

Comment: Sean, Message lock duration is 10 seconds configured in Azure service bus portal when creating the queues. I also tried it with 1 minute and 5 minutes.

Comment: If you reduce the `number of messages` from 1500 to 100, can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @SeanFeldman : No it comes with high number of messages. 100 messages are no problem. The strange thing is that it gives an error at the first message. And trying to restart it a couple of times then it proceeds. Really strange. Maybe I have to use message chunks for example a for loopt with 15 loops and 100 messages each? Maybe I run into limitations because we don't use the Premium version ?

Comment: Receiving that many messages in a single receive operation will have some impacting the performance, but was thinking about lock/lease being lost for the tail of the messages. Also, are you always guaranteed to get all 1500 that you're requesting? I remember ASB only returning a sunset, never a full set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the high number of messages I tried to proceed at once. So I rebuild my solution so that it processes 100 messages max per batch.
Thanks Sean for your support.